# Streaming & HTTP Clients (General Industry Question)

Tags: api, rest, http, streaming, apigee

Apologies if this question is rather basic, but do most HTTP clients support streaming requests and responses by default?

We are onboarding an API management solution that enforces a max 10MB payload size unless streaming is enabled (Apigee). Our existing API framework allows for requests/responses with large JSON payloads, so I'm trying to assess the potential impact on our current API consumers to plan for change management. In general, what are some things to consider?